#  require file use dirname(__FILE__) or just require filename?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a file at lib directory in my rails project. like this
a (directory)
  a1 
  a2
a.rb

when I in a.rb require a1.

```
require 'a/a1'
```

it will warn me /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- a/a1 (MissingSourceFile)

but use dirname(**FILE**), it work.

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/a/a1
```

why?

Answer (score 2):

The code:

```
requie 'a/a1'
```

will try to find the directory a from the current working directory, which may not be what you think, especially if executing from an environment other than the command line (rails console, or textmate for example).

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/a/a1
```

appends '/a/a1 to the path of the file in which that line appears, so you are sure of always getting the right file, whichever environment you're operating in.